# logstash -> Elasticsearch: update denormalized data

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kafka-consumer-api, logstash-configuration

I have encountered a problem similar to the one mentioned in the URL below.
[Logstash -> Elasticsearch - update denormalized data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976143/logstash-elasticsearch-update-denormalized-data?rq=1)
I got the events from kafka

Answer (score 0):

How are you get events?

It might be easiest to write your agent which goes an update elasticsearch data based on change field.

If you are using Kafka to get this data, you may simply write this in Kafka consumer where you get all documents from elasticsearch based on field that has changed. Update json results to update with new data and then update that back in Elasticsearch.

Effort of writing this may not be much. 2-3 hours should be good enough.

Comment: Thanks very much. I got the events from kafka.What you mean is: I need to call elasticsearch in the kafka client to get the documents that need to be updated?

Comment: Yes. I feel that will easier way to do it.