# Does Logstash support Elasticsearch's _update_by_query?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Does the Elasticsearch output plugin support elasticsearch's _update_by_query?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.5/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `elasticsearch` output plugin can only make calls to the `_bulk` endpoint, i.e. using the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

If you want to call the Update by Query API, you need to use the [`http`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-http.html) output plugin and construct the query inside the event yourself. If you explain what you want to achieve, I can update my answer with some more details.

Note: There's an [issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/443) requesting this feature, but it's still open after two years.

**UPDATE**

So if your input event is `{"cname":"wang", "cage":11}` and you want to update by query all documents with `"cname":"wang"` to set `"cage":11`, your query needs to look like this:

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.cage = params.cage",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "cage": 11
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "cname": "wang"
    }
  }
}
```

So your Logstash config should look like this (your input may vary but I used `stdin` for testing purposes):

```
input {
  stdin {
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "[script][lang]" => "painless"
      "[script][source]" => "ctx._source.cage = params.cage"
      "[script][params][cage]" => "%{cage}"
      "[query][term][cname]" => "%{cname}"
    }
    remove_field => ["host", "@version", "@timestamp", "cname", "cage"]
  }
}
output {
  http {
    url => "http://localhost:9200/index/doc/_update_by_query"
    http_method => "post"
    format => "json"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I have a question. If my logstash input is "{"cname":wang, "cage":11}" and I want to update all documents with cname=wang and set cage to 11, how should I write the logstash conf file to achieve it? Thank you

Comment: Hi, We tried this http response in logstash, the elastic search console throws error for index not found and log stash results in 400: [HTTP Output Failure] Encountered non-2xx HTTP code 405 {:response_code=>405, :url=>"http://localhost:9200%2Ftest_index%2F_doc%2F_update_by_query", :event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x54b1.  no such index
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.indexNotFoundException(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:728) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]

Comment: @Val, can you please help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67752722/elasticsearch-update-by-query-in-logstash-error-http-output-failure-encounter)?

Answer (score -1):

The same result can be obtained with standard elasticsearch plugins:

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "${ES_HOSTS}"
        user => "${ES_USER}"
        password => "${ES_PWD}"
        index => "<your index pattern>"
        size => 500
        scroll => "5m"
        docinfo => true
    }
}

filter {
    ...
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "${ES_HOSTS}"
        user => "${ES_USER}"
        password => "${ES_PWD}"
        action => "update"
        document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
        index => "%{[@metadata][_index]}"
    }
}
```