# Logstash bulk update documens in ElasticSearch with WHERE conditon

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I have 2 tables in MySQL like this

Table `DEPARTMENT`

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Department 1 |
| 2 | Department 2 |

Table `STAFF`

| Id | Department_Id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Staff 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Staff 2 |
| 3 | 2 | Staff 3 |
| 4 | 1 | Staff 4 |

- `STAFF` table has about 10 million records.

All `STAFF`'s informations has been pushed by Logstash to ElasticSearch. Each document in ElasticSearch now only have 3 fields are `Staff_Id`, `Staff_Name` and `Department_Name`. Something like this:

```
{
    "Staff_Id": 1,
    "Staff_Name": "Staff 1",
    "Department_Name": "Department 1"
}
```

Because of practical needs, I need to add one more field called `Department_Id` to each document. Note that this field (`Department_Id`) does not exist on existing documents.

I am a newbie to both Logstash and ElasticSearch. How can I do this with Logstash? Interpreted in the SQL way would be:

- SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT;
- UPDATE STAFF SET Department_Id = XXX WHERE Department_Name = YYY

Note that `DEPARTMENT`  table has about 100.000 records and ElasticSearch has about 10 million documents.
Can you take a look?

Comment: can you provide your logstash configuration ? also, while indexing document from logstash, did you provided custom doc_id or it is auto generated ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Logstash support Elasticsearch's \_update\_by\_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330232/does-logstash-support-elasticsearchs-update-by-query)